# How to install Viber in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, viber

Is it possible to install Viber VoIP client on Ubuntu? So that I can call people through Viber from my PC.

Comment: @Partha the second answer is a DEB . make sure that you are using a 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: to all users who have been trying to install viber from the source are requested to use DEB method .Thank you.

Comment: updated answer for the issue of �: not found

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Viber has released  its official client for Ubuntu/Linux. To install it, open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
wget https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
```

Then unzip it and `cd` to that viber directory. Then do as:

```
unzip Viber.zip
cd Viber
~/Viber/Viber.sh
```

That will install Viber in your Ubuntu.

**How to install in .DEB way** // Currently only 64-bit available

Open your terminal and type:

```
wget -O viber.deb https://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb  
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

That's it. You can access Viber in your Ubuntu.

**Update** : I came to know that some of the users are getting

```
home/$USERNAME/Viber/Viber: 1: /home/$USERNAME/Viber/Viber: �: not found
/home/$USERNAME/Viber/Viber: 1: /home/$USERNAME/Viber/Viber: ELF: not found
/home/$USERNAME/Viber/Viber: 1: /home/$USERNAME/Viber/Viber: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

so that Issue can be fixed by ["♦: command not found" in tty after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307770/command-not-found-in-tty-after-login/309547#309547) post.

Comment: I've unpacked it under **~/.Viber** and this beta version also works perfectly well this way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between ~/Viber/Viber.sh and ./Viber.sh (while in the directory)? 

Thanks.

Comment: after cd to Viber you just need to do either ./Viber or ./Viber.sh both are same. If you do not cd to viber then with single command  ~/Viber/Viber.sh you can do it.

Comment: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/09/viber-available-for-linux-install-in.html gives description with .deb and installation instructions.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect Thank you I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Radu Rădeanu Thank you for the answer about the :not found issue.

Comment: It's 64 bit, is there any 32 bit version?

Comment: @user Actually Ubuntu is now multiarch , you can install it.

Comment: As far as I can tell you cannot run Viber.sh on a 32bit system.

Answer (score 9):

Download deb package from [viber.com](http://viber.com/products/linux/)

Install the `.deb` package:

```
cd /viber_download_location/

sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

If you are running 32bit system use

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i viber.deb
```

Comment: I'm not able to open / run viber. I'm using 14.04 (x86). Is there any other way to fix that ?

Comment: The 32bit system command installs Viber but it cannot be started

Comment: What's the point in `--force-architecture`? It'll install an unusable package.

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 18.04

Open terminal

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Type in terminal -

```
username:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for user: 
root:/home/user/# add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
root:/home/user/# apt install flatpak
root:/home/user/# apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
root:/home/user/# exit
username:~$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
username:~$ sudo reboot
[sudo] password for user:
```

Your system will now reboot.

Open terminal

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Type in terminal -

```
username:~$ flatpak search viber
Application ID  Version Branch Remotes Description
com.viber.Viber       Stable flathub We connect people, no metter who they are or where they are from.
username:~$ flatpak install flathub com.viber.Viber
Required runtime for com.viber.Viber/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/18.08) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [y/n]: y
Installing in system:
//some code
//some code
//some code
Is this ok [y/n]: y
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/18.08 from flathub
//some code
//some code
//some code
Installing: com.viber.Viber/x86_64/stable from flathub
//some code
//some code
//some code
username:~$
```

Open **Viber** from dash