# Viber icon missing on panel

Tags: 12.04, unity, icons, panel, viber

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I've installed Viber and I'm struggling for days with this problem. My Viber icon is located at the top left corner, few milimeters to the right from the dash icon. 
I have tried to whitelist it on desktop enviroment variables, it wroked with Skype, but not with Viber. Please help.

Comment: Are you install viber using terminal ?

Comment: No, I've used the .deb package from their site.

Comment: Try install with terminal [http://askubuntu.com/questions/340924/how-to-install-viber-in-ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340924/how-to-install-viber-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I've tried installing it with terminal. Its the same problem as before.

Comment: Screenshot please

Comment: are the program Viber is already installed ?

Comment: If the program viber is already installed and can opened, i will gave you my answer

Comment: Are you follow method at [Viber Official Site](http://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1435703-viber-setup-for-linux#.UzJGKVSSx39) ?

Comment: I don't have reputation 10 so here's the link for screenshot. http://imgur.com/BuBlKqM

Answer (score 0):

Before do this ways, install gnome fallback first by running this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

And if the proccess is finish, log out and change desktop environment by clicking ubuntu logo near login field, choose Gnome Fallback and then log in back.

1. Place your cursor on panel
2. Press Super + Alt + Right Click, and you will see the option. Click "add to panel" and choose "add application". Then click at "Viber", click "OK".
3. You will se Viber Icons on panel

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I'll upload my screnshot.

Comment: @Tomislav sorry iam late, now i understand u want add viber icons at panel. Hmmm, i don't know how to do it in unity. But if you change from unity to gnome. I know how ! Follow my answer