# Viber Installation error (Status_Custom_Error)

Tags: 14.04, wine, viber

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit.

I got the error`Status_Custom_Error`as shown in picture. I have tried installing Wine but it doesn't work well.

How can I install it properly?

[image: skype error]

I have even tried [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340924/how-to-install-viber-in-ubuntu?rq=1).

Comment: read here it was asked before 3 years ago http://askubuntu.com/questions/340924/how-to-install-viber-in-ubuntu

Comment: I have already tired that.

Answer (score 1):

work step by step from [here](https://www.viber.com/en/products/linux)

1. Download Viber Debian
2. Install with ubuntu software
3. Enter your phone that Viber installed on
4. Scan the QR