# Viber install problems

Tags: viber

I followed the instructions shown here: [How to install Viber in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340924/how-to-install-viber-in-ubuntu)

```
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
unzip Viber.zip
cd Viber
```

All was fine, but the last command doesn't work:

```
$ ~/Viber/Viber.sh
/home/erik/Viber/Viber: 1: /home/erik/Viber/Viber: �: not found
/home/erik/Viber/Viber: 1: /home/erik/Viber/Viber: /home/erik/Viber/Viber: 1: /home/erik/Viber/Viber: ELF: not found
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

If I write:

```
$ Viber.sh
Viber.sh: command not found
```

But Viber.sh is in the directory:

```
$ ls
??????@??              libQt5OpenGL.so.5         libViber.so
imageformats           libQt5PrintSupport.so.5   libXss.so.1
libbfd-2.22-system.so  libQt5Qml.so.5            ??ME@H
libicudata.so.48       libQt5Quick.so.5          platforms
libicui18n.so.48       libQt5Sql.so.5            Sound
libicuuc.so.48         libQt5Svg.so.5            sqldrivers
libQt5Core.so.5        libQt5V8.so.5             Viber
libQt5DBus.so.5        libQt5WebKit.so.5         Viber_icon.png
libQt5Gui.so.5         libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5  Viber.sh
libQt5Network.so.5     libQt5Widgets.so.5
```

I also got a Viber icon in Dash, but clicking on it does not open Viber

Comment: Try to re-download it. I can install Viber on my 64-bit xenial by following your instruction.

Comment: Can you try `bash Viber.sh`? I think Viber.sh is using dash shell, which might be causing the issue.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `file ~/Viber/Viber.sh; md5sum ~/Viber/Viber.sh; sh -n ~/Viber/Viber.sh`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you have followed is an old thread. Probably there might be some issue with the version. I recommend you to go to the official website for downloading the Debian package ([Link](https://www.viber.com/products/linux/)).

After downloading, performing
`sudo dpkg -i file_name.deb` will help you to install the package.

**Note**: Links are subjected to change and could be broken. Always refer the official website for confirming version of any package before downloading.