# Error when I open the terminal: `bash: /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash: No such file or directory`

Tags: command-line, bash

[image]

I've uninstalled ROS with:

```
sudo apt-get purge ros-*
```

Then when I open terminal I get this message. I have no idea how to solve it.

P.S. Because of the error I can't install ROS again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `~/bashrc` file (using `gedit ~/bashrc` command) and search for this string: `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash`. If you find if, remove the code which is using it. If no, search in the other [shell initialization files](http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_03_01.html). It should be somewhere.

The files that contain initialization commands when a shell is invoked are: `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_aliases` and maybe others. See [Shell initialization files](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html).

To quickly check if one of these files have something wrong inside, you can use `source` command. For example:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

See also: ["♦: command not found" in tty after login](https://askubuntu.com/q/307770/147044)

Comment: I found that string in ~/.bashrc file and deleted it and it works :) Thank you @Radu