# Default path changed after uninstalling python and reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I was trying to uninstall python3 from ubuntu 12.04 with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3*
```

and it just remove many things from system, including the ubuntu-desktop. After that, I reinstalled the desktop with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

The problem is that, when I open a terminal, it shows me a

```
~
```

sign on top off the screen, and didn't start from home, as in

```
nilson@GHOSTRIDER~$
```

What's wrong and how can I correct this?

For details see the marked area in the following picture:

[image: terminal and prompt exhibit]

Comment: is there any ~ character present in your .bashrc file?If yes then delete it and then source your .bashrc file.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["♦: command not found" in tty after login](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307770/command-not-found-in-tty-after-login)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm sorry man, but i've look in `.bashrc`, `.profile` and there's no `~` char present. But, another problem is that, when I type `cd to_any_dir`, it show the dir in new line. See the picture in the link above.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PS1` command?

Comment: `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[01;31m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;34m\]\u\[\033[01;32m\]@\[\033[01;34m\]\h\[\033[00m\]\$ $(parse_git_branch)$(parse_svn_branch)`

Comment: Thank You @RaduRădeanu, the problem was with the $PS1 variable in the `~/.bashrc`. There was another line above, and I just uncomment it and comment the second one. The new `echo $PS1` is `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ $(parse_git_branch)$(parse_svn_branch)`. Thank You All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP wrote:

> [...]the problem was with the `$PS1` variable in the `~/.bashrc`. There was
>   another line above, and I just uncomment it and comment the second
>   one. The new `echo $PS1` is `\[\e]0;\u@\h:
>   \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[‌​01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ $(parse_git_branch)$(parse_svn_branch)`.